# How to change the color of an image while keeping its nuances?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I have this .jpg in Compositor:

[image]

[Full Image on GDrive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_PEYjpiM1fsN5jJDHJ9-E11g31tyx-8U/view?usp=sharing)

My goal is to change the color of your choice while keeping:
-more or less large white dots
-the proportion of gradations in the same places and the same nuances

I guess Blender compositing can do that, but I don't.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Hello :). Could you please mark one of the answers as accepted **✓**? Thank you :).

Answer (score 3):

Here is one of many ways to do this:

1. Add *Color ramp* node - use it to adjust whites/blacks
2. Add *Mix node* set to *Screen* - it will filter out the black parts
3. Connect *RGB node* and select your desired color

[image]